# Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein Contradiction

Tags: proof-writing

I need help figuring out where to start a proof that says I should use a proof by contradiction.

$f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to A$ be functions and each is 1-1. Let $D$ be the range of $f$ (i.e., $D=f(A)$).

Let $x$ and $y$ be natural numbers with $x>y$.  Prove: $g(fg)^x (B-D)\cap g(fg)^y (B-D)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start with the simplest case: $x=1$ and $y=0$.  (I'm going to consider $0$ to be a "natural number"; not everybody does so.)  Then the statement to prove is
$$ gfg(B-D)\cap g(B-D) = \emptyset $$
To prove that some set is empty by contradiction, I'd start by assuming the opposite, that is, suppose the set is nonempty.  That gives me something concrete to work with: an element in the set.  Then I look for things that I can say about that element.

So, to start:

> Suppose, on the contrary, that $gfg(B-D)\cap g(B-D)\ne\emptyset$.  Let $x\in gfg(B-D)\cap g(B-D)$.

Then... what?  What can you say about $x$?  What have we already said about $x$?

Comment: Then x ∈ B? I'm not exactly sure where your leading me right now..

Comment: Actually $x\in A$.  But yes, that kind of thing.  What else can we say?  For example, what does it mean when we say that $x\in\text{BLAH}\cap\text{BLEE}$?

Comment: That x exists in both BLAH and BLEE

Comment: And if x exists in BLAH and BLEE then the intersection is not empty.

Comment: Good.  What are BLAH and BLEE here, and what does it mean for $x$ to be in each of them?

Comment: That BLAH and BLEE are not empty.

Comment: No, I mean you told me that $x$ is in BLEE.  In the text, BLEE is $g(B-D)$.  What does it mean to say $x\in g(B-D)$?  (I don't mean "what does it mean" like "what consequences does it have", I mean, "what is the literal meaning of these symbols".)

Comment: That x exists in the function g(B-D)

Comment: And, what does $g(B-D)$ mean?

Comment: Hm.  Ok, I think we'd better cut it short here; it seems you don't know the notations involved in the question, and addressing that would require quite a bit more time than I have.  Maybe you can find someone to work with you in person on this?

Comment: Thanks for you help anyways. I think i got it wish i could talk to you in person. I feel it can be hard getting what i'm trying to say through symbols sometimes

Answer (score 0):

If $g(fg)^x(B-D)∩g(fg)^y(B-D)≠∅$ let a belong to the intersection of the two sets. Then there are u, v in B-D such that $g(fg)^x(u)=g(fg)^y(v)=a$. Then $(fg)^x(u)=(fg)^y(v)$ because we can multiply each side of the first equality by $g^{-1}$, which is 1-1, and get the second equality. But then $(fg)^{-y}(fg)^x(u)=(fg)^{-y}(fg)^y(v)$ and thus 
$(fg)^{x-y}(u)=v$. But fg(u) is not in B-D and so also every $(fg)^n(u)$ is not in D-B for every natural number n (because fg is 1-1 and thus it preserves the disjointedness of sets), but v is in B-D so we get a contradiction.

Incidentally, (fg)^x is a (commonly used) misnomer because fg need not be applied again to get to the xth image of a member form B-D.